# Are questions about identifying mushroom species on-topic here?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I've found a mushroom and will not going to eat it anyways but still quite interested in what kind of mushroom it's actually is.

Does this count as an on-topic here? If not, can it still somehow to be improved to be on-topic?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are on-topic, but please see https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info and follow the guidelines there (including the one specific note about mycology).

In general, species identification questions are best when they have a bit of flair to them, rather than just "What is this?" So any details you can provide about the mushroom that you have found and why you care to have it identified will be helpful.